# Changing values of members inside a Generic List in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Below is a simple C++/CLI example.

```
// TestCLR.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::Collections::Generic::List<String^> TestList;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        TestList.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    for each(String^% st in TestList)
    {
        st += "TEST";
        Console::WriteLine(st);
    }

    for each(String^ st in TestList)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(st);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
0TEST
1TEST
2TEST
3TEST
4TEST
5TEST
6TEST
7TEST
8TEST
9TEST
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

In short, the values inside **TestList** do not change even though I am using a tracking pointer to change its value to "TEST".

What should I modify in the above snippet so that the value is permanently changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `System::Collections::Generic::List`, which uses a property to access items.  You can't bind a tracking reference to a property, you end up with a reference to a temporary copy of the value instead.

That code would work for an array, but `foreach` can't be used to mutate elements in-place in a container.  You'll need a for loop, because you need the index to overwrite list elements:

```
for(int i = 0, cnt = TestList.Count; i < cnt; ++i)
{
    TestList[i] += "TEST";
    Console::WriteLine(TestList[i]);

    // doesn't work right: String^% st = TestList[i];
    // since TestList[i] is not an lvalue, it's a function call to a getter method
}
```

Didn't you get a compiler warning telling you that you were binding a non-const reference to a temporary object?

Comment: No I did not get any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting help from the compiler here.  It is a [CS1656 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/369xac69.aspx) in C# but the C++/CLI compiler forgets to give you a diagnostic.

The foreach iteration variable is an alias for the `IEnumerable<T>::Current` property.  Which only has a getter, it doesn't have a setter.  So it can never update the underlying collection.  You'll need to use a plain for() loop here.

Comment: The C# case is hardly comparable, since C# doesn't support tracking references at all.  Furthermore, the problem is not the lack of a setter on the property, it's that a tracking reference doesn't bind to a property's accessor functions, but only to the temporary returned from the getter.  This is just another manifestation of the VC++ bug that allows binding non-`const` references to temporaries, despite being forbidden by the standard.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I tried the same example in C# and intellisense itself showed an error when I tried to assign the value inside foreach.